# Browser based SQL Client for Non Technical Users

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, client

Looking for a browser (or application) based client for a SQL database (MySQL or PostgreSQL) for non-technical users. Simply speaking I am looking for a GUI to update, insert and delete rows in existing tables without the need to write a SQL query. This can be as lightweight (but preferably modern looking) and basic as necessary as all schema changes will be made by a DBA in the normal way.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the 2 most popular:

- For MySQL: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
- For PostgreSQL: https://pgadmin.org/